# scala socket client doesn't get response after sending binary data to python server

Tags: python, scala, sockets, base64, serversocket

I used Scala socket client to send binary data to Python server. I found the Python socket server not be able to read the data from Scala client. I tried adding \r\n on the tail of the message, but no any effects. The following is my Scala client code please:

```
val s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SOCKET), 5000)
s.setSoTimeout(120*1000)
val inputStream = s.getInputStream()
val bufferSource = new BufferedSource(inputStream)
val out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream())
lazy val in = bufferSource.getLines()
//send data to python server socket
theData:Array[Byte] = //The data comes from SparkStreaming, it's byte array.
out.println(theData)
out.flush()
if(in.hasNext){
   val json1 = in.next()
}
```

The following is my Python server code please:

```
class TCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
            self.data = self.rfile.read()
            if not self.data:
                break
            output=calculate256(self.data)
            self.wfile.write(json.dumps(output)+'\n')
```

The interesting thing is that if I encode the data with base64 and use readline() instead of read() function, it then works. But we have to transfer binary data for processing, so readline() is not suitable for us. I highly appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  of your client and server?

Comment: Thank you so much Bacon, I modified the question with more detailed code. The problem is the Python Server Side even not be able to get the data from Scala client. So no further action after the read() function in Python side. Does Scala and Python socket need any protocol or specified code format, but I use python client to access python server was totally fine.

Comment: It seems I need to add the following line: socket.shutdownOutput()